# AWS IAM force certain tag for all instances deployed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm creating a lab and I want the ec2 instances my lab users create to be forced to

1. fill in a Owner tag.
2. limit them to only be able to launch m4.xl and m4.2xl ***edit no longer care what instance they select***
3. when deploying allow them to select a specific role (for some reason full ec2 access denies them the access to select a role)

here's my current policy i've attached to the lab users

```
   {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },

    **{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::186473000259:role/lab_users"
        }**,

        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudwatch:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "autoscaling:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any info would be great!

Comment: You can restrict instance types (example https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=174503).

Comment: I dont mind that they can select different instance types my problem is when they launch an instance and they try to slect the lab-user role , that part is greyed out. This is even though I added the action of passing in the role. I assumed this would allow them to select it.